# How to use custom delimiters in Sumologic regex parsing

Tags: sumologic

The standard Sumologic regex delimiter is the double-quote, like so:

```
parse regex "(?<ip_address>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
```

That becomes problematic when you're parsing a message that contains many double-quotes, as you would need to escape each instance.  Is there a way to define a custom delimiter?

I've tried things like

```
parse regex /(?<ip_address>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/
```